# How to handle delimiter of path string in chrome and IE for donut slices using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get the position of the four ends of the donut slices of arcs created using d3.js. If you see this diagram:
[image: Donut slices]
In IE the donut slice gets the following string:

```
M -318.303 -27.631 A 319.5 319.5 0 0 1 -313.043 -63.9105 L -69.6404 -13.828 A 71 71 0 0 0 -70.7 -6.52054 Z
```

and in chrome the similar slice gets us the following string:

```
M-312.4,-3.8257966005363313e-14A312.4,312.4 0 0,1 -311.29259530331694,-26.280793544437252L-77.82314882582924,-6.570198386109313A78.1,78.1 0 0,0 -78.1,-9.564491501340828e-15Z
```

The approach I am using is to use fragments after splitting the 'd' parameter of the arc using the delimiter ' '(space) or ','(comma). Like this:

```
var fragment18A = d3.select(this).attr("d").split(",")[18];
var fragment19 = d3.select(this).attr("d").split(",")[19];
var fragment20 = d3.select(this).attr("d").split(",")[20];
var fragment0 = d3.select(this).attr("d").split(",")[0];
var fragment1 = d3.select(this).attr("d").split(",")[1];
var fragment25, fragment26;
```

How do I write javascript code that gets me the four end points in chrome and IE with the same code?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmkamath2000/d0pe4bjL/3/) is a js fiddle of some old code that has problem displaying the slices in IE.
unfortunately js fiddle does not work in IE(you will have to download the html and run locally).

Comment: Easier to use this to parse: https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill

Comment: @RobertLongson the sample test code for path data polyfill contained an arrow function and some assignments that were throwing errors in IE. I worked around the problem and am getting expected output in both IE and chrome. Not sure if we can use third party libraries in my organization. Thanks.

Comment: you're already using a third-party library: **d3**